# scrapyd deploy job fails with unable to open database file

Tags: python, scrapyd

I am running a batch of 500 crawl jobs on scrapyd fired from a     shell script. I am having this issue locally on mac as well as on ec2     instance.
        These crawl jobs have been working fine with a batch of 100 however     when i run it for 500 it throws "sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open     database file" exception after about 300.

Note: Each crawl(one spider) is a project and is deployed on scrapyd, which means it would have 500 projects deployed.

After about 300 crawls are done I start seeing this exception and cannot deploy anymore projects. If I restart the scrapyd server it will not restart again, throws the same exception.

Only way i can get to start again and crawl again is by

1. stopping the server
2. rm -rf dbs files
3. rm -rf eggs (probably not required)
4. rm -rf logs (probably not required)
5. start server

   Any ideas why this would happen?
   Here is the exception

   ```
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info] 1
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info] Traceback (most recent call last):
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/runner.py", line 39, in <module>
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/runner.py", line 34, in main
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/runner.py", line 13, in project_environment
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/__init__.py", line 14, in get_application
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/app.py", line 37, in application
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/website.py", line 35, in __init__
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/website.py", line 38, in update_projects
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/poller.py", line 30, in update_projects
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/utils.py", line 61, in get_spider_queues
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/spiderqueue.py", line 12, in __init__
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info]   File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/sqlite.py", line 98, in __init__
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [stdout#info] sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
   2017-04-13T23:28:57+0000 [_GenericHTTPChannelProtocol,673,10.0.3.119] Unhandled Error
           Traceback (most recent call last):
             File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 1845, in allContentReceived
               req.requestReceived(command, path, version)
             File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 766, in requestReceived
               self.process()
             File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 190, in process
               self.render(resrc)
             File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 241, in render
               body = resrc.render(self)
           --- <exception caught here> ---
             File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/webservice.py", line 17, in render
               return JsonResource.render(self, txrequest)
             File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/utils.py", line 19, in render
               r = resource.Resource.render(self, txrequest)
             File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/resource.py", line 250, in render
               return m(request)
             File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/webservice.py", line 68, in render_POST
               spiders = get_spider_list(project)
             File "/home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/utils.py", line 116, in get_spider_list
               raise RuntimeError(msg.splitlines()[-1])
           exceptions.RuntimeError: sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
   ```

   I am guessing scrapyd after 300 projects is running out of space which is why popen fails but looks like the box has some space. 
   Any pointers will be helpful.

   I am running scrapyd 1.3.3 on ec2 instance with default config and python 2.7.

   Doing lsof on the dbs folder shows me two entries for each .db file.
   Is this expected?

   ```
   scrapyd    6363 ec2-user 1005u      REG              202,1      2048   148444 /home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/bin/dbs/LatamPtBlogGenesysCom.db
   scrapyd    6363 ec2-user 1006u      REG              202,1      2048   148444 /home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/bin/dbs/LatamPtBlogGenesysCom.db
   scrapyd    6363 ec2-user 1007u      REG              202,1      2048   148503 /home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/bin/dbs/WwwPeeblesshirenewsCom.db
   scrapyd    6363 ec2-user 1009u      REG              202,1      2048   148503 /home/ec2-user/scrapyENV/bin/dbs/WwwPeeblesshirenewsCom.db
   ```